# AlarmManager at two specific times

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

i have two AlarmManager at 9:00 and 21:00, but only run the second alarm.

```
    ////////9:00am/////////
    Intent aviso = new Intent(FijarAlerta.this,Servicio.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 0, aviso, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           //set the hour
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pi);
```

The second alarm

```
////////21:00pm//////////
    Intent avisopm = new Intent(FijarAlerta.this,Servicio.class);
    PendingIntent pipm = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 0, avisopm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                 //set the hour
    Calendar calpm = Calendar.getInstance();
    calpm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calpm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calpm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager ampm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    ampm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calpm.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pipm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of your call to `PendingIntent.getService()` should be a different number in each case. For example:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 111, aviso,       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
PendingIntent pipm = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 222, avisopm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

At the moment the second pendingIntent just overwrites the first

Comment: I can change the "cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);" in the first alarm for "cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);" and remove the second alarm? Is the same?

Comment: They aren't exactly the same: HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Comment: If I want to run at 8 and 20, I put the two alarms necessarily?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your second alarm line:

```
PendingIntent pipm = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 0, avisopm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

with below one

```
PendingIntent pipm = PendingIntent.getService(FijarAlerta.this, 1, avisopm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Now, try and let me comment if you not get success.

Enjoy Coding. :)